# Defining tuple in CPLEX

Tags: tuples, cplex

I want to define a tuple in a CPLEX .mod file. There is a main block in the .mod file. When I try to define the tuple inside the main block, an error occurs like: `Scripting parser error: missing ';' or newline between statements`. This is shown in the next figure:

[image]

But when I replace the tuple definition out of the main block, the problem is solved. Like the next figure:

[image]

Although the problem is solved with the second approach, I want to ask what is the reason for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the main block you should use thisOplModel to get anything from the model.

```
tuple minandmax
{
int m;
int M;
}

{minandmax} singletonMinAndMax={<1,5>};

dvar int X;
subject to
{
  
}

main
{
  writeln("give me ",Opl.first(thisOplModel.singletonMinAndMax).M);
}
```

gives

```
give me 5
```